# gitignore file problem : Not able to ignore node_modules

Tags: visual-studio-code, node-modules, gitignore

I have one **.gitignore** file for my mern app.

I want to ignore all `node_modules` ( in client-side and server) but I am only able to ignore client's node_modules. It also not ignore `.env` file. What could be the reason? Can anyone answer me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6rrt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try once removing .env & node_module from the cache once

```
git rm .env --cached
git rm -r --cached .
```

also for `node_module` you can try keeping

```
/node_module
node_module
.env
```

or else try `**node_modules`